# Custom buttons for HTML select box in PhoneGap

Tags: html, select, cordova

I want to change the default buttons of an HTML select box (dropdown) using PhoneGap 3.5. A "Cancel" button should appear in addition to "Done." Is it possible to change or add select buttons using the PhoneGap API or plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using the OS level control out of the box but it looks like a cordova plugin (for iOS) has been started (3 days ago) that could include this functionality:

https://github.com/mzbyszynski/cordova-plugin-picker

I suggest speaking directly with the plugin author by raising an issue / enhancement request.